# Duplicate Rule does not apply when condition is fulfilled only after update

Tags: duplicate-management

I have a custom object with the following fields:

1. `active__c` (Checkbox)
2. `value__c` (Text)

I want to make sure there are no two active records that have the field `value__c` populated with the same data, so I tried using duplicate rules.

I added a matching rule that matches iff the data in `value__c` is the same and then I added a duplicate rule that uses that matching rule with the condition that `active__c` is true. This duplicate rule is set to block on creation and on edit if a duplicate is found.

This does not work as I want it though. For reproduction you can do the following:

1. create two records
2. set `active__c` to `false` on both
3. set `value__c` to `abc` (or any other string) on both.
4. set `active__c` to `true` on one of them.
5. set `active__c` to `true` on the other one too.

The duplicate rule does not execute despite the fact that there are now two active records with the same value.

This seems like a bug to me, but if not, is there a way to do this using duplicate rules?

If there is not, are there any other standard functionalities I can use?

I want to try to solve this without using apex, flows, processes or workflows since they need a little more maintenance.

Comment: worth checking [things to know about Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_overview.htm&type=5); I know I've been burned realizing that duplicate rules don't apply to dups intrabatch